# Row cell value from List

Tags: c#, .net, list, loops, datagridview

I'm trying to get foreach item in List to set foreach cell value in a specific column **starting from second row.**
for example

```
List Items

123 

456

Col1

void this cell

123

456
```

Here is my code so far:

```
foreach (var item in list.items)
{
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in myDgv.Rows)
  {
    row.Cells[0].Value = item;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use for loop instead of foreach loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < list.items.Count; i ++)
{
    myDgv.Rows[i + 1].Cells[0].Value = list.items[i];
 }
```